Is there any way to implement GARCH-MIDAS model in R for multivariate estimation?
I'm writing a research paper in economics, and would like to research the impact of both financial and macroeconomic variables on the NIFTY50 index. My plan was to use a GARCH model. I've stumbled across the GARCH-MIDAS model which seems perfect, since many macrovariables are only in a monthly or quarterly or annual format, while the stock return is daily.
I've searched the internet for a R package that can support the model, but all the packages I find are only univariate, while I have several explanatory variables I want to include.
I've looked at the packages mfGARCH, GarchMidas, mcsGARCH, rumidas, rmgarch and midasr, but it seems that none of them both support multiple variables while still estimating GARCH models.

duplicate of https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/76743/is-there-any-way-to-estimate-a-multivariate-garch-midas-model-in-r ?

I'm also facing a similar problem. Have you resolved it?
